# Datepicker for Bootstrap, date selection errors for check in/out

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using the bootstrap date picker and running into some errors. If you look at [this page](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) you will see an example of a check in, check out selector.

If I select Feb 8th as my arrival date and Feb 9th as my departure date and then select Feb 3st as my arrival date, I am unable to immediately select Feb 4nd as my departure date. I have to click in the page and then select the departure again. This might be as simple as  saying if the arrival date is changed, refresh what the departure date shows in the drop down before displaying it.

[Here is the page Im using it on.](http://94co.com/client5/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

That is may be due to if condition in changedate event of "checkin".

try it by that commenting if condition

Comment: commenting out that if statement allows you to select any date at any time thus removing the function I am only trying to improve upon. I want the user to be able to select any date now or in the future in both calendars. If the change there mind I want them to be able to go back and select different dates. Right now that is only possible if theose dates are AFTER the first dates selected....this is an issue from the original code as well.

Comment: I have added this issue to Github here https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/803